# How to crop visible part of a bitmap in an ImageView if it is scaled

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, scale

Assume I have an image which is larger than an `ImageView` size (width and height) and the `scaleType` is set to `CENTER` or the `scaleType` is set to `MATRIX` and the bitmap is translated and scaled. Therefore parts of the image are not visible. How may I calculate the visible part of the bitmap and crop exact that part. I want to crop and store only the visible part.

How may I do that?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want exactly what the image view shows?  I'd enable the drawing cache and grab it from the view.  That should be exactly what's on screen.

Comment: Dude, Thanks for your exact :) answer!